# How to read a nested json file in flutter and bind the values to dependent dropdowns

Tags: json, flutter, dropdown, hierarchy

Json file has hierarchy as following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "area": [
      {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "Ghatkoapr",
        "subArea": [
          {
            "id": 10101,
            "name": "Pantnagar"
          }
        ]
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Pune",
    "area": [
      {
        "id": 201,
        "name": "Shivajinagar",
        "subArea": [
          {
            "id": 20101,
            "name": "Model Colony"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to bind city value to first dropdown and its dependent areas to second dropdown and subareas to third dropdown.

I am new to flutter. I have tried many approaches but didnt help. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you have any code?